# Display Count of String (array?) from Parse to UIView UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform

I have an app built in Xcode using Objective-C that saves data to Parse.com.  The user sends memories to the parse.com database.

I am trying to display the number (count) of memories sent by the current user.

The storyboard I want this displayed on is a UIViewController and there is plenty of room for a single line of text at the bottom of the page.  So, I inserted a Table View from the Xcode Object Library, and then inserted a Table View Cell with 1 prototype Cell with a reuse identifier of "cellCount".

I have set up the ViewController as the Delegate and DataSource for the UITableView, and I have linked the cell to the ViewController header file.

I am now completely stuck, and I just need some help. I worked on this for about 12 hours today, so please take pity on me. Take a look and see if there are some obvious errors in my code.  THANKS!!!

## import "MemoriesViewController.h"

MemoriesViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

    
    
    @interface MemoriesViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
    
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    
    @property (nonatomic, strong) PFQuery *query;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *mainArray;
    
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellCount;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *memoriesField;
    
    - (IBAction)sendMemories:(UIButton *)sender;
    - (IBAction)logOut:(id)sender;
    
    @end
```

MemoriesViewController.m

```
#import "MemoriesViewController.h"
    @interface MemoriesViewController ()
    
    @end
    
    @implementation MemoriesViewController
    
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
        }
        
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
            [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        
        PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
        if (currentUser) {
            NSLog(@"Current user: %@", currentUser.username);
        }
        else {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
        }
        self.memoriesField.delegate = self;
        _mainArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", nil];
    }
    #pragma mark - Table view data source
    
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfSectionsInTableView:(NSInteger)section {
        return [_mainArray count];
        }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableViewCell *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Memories"];
        [query whereKey:@"senderName" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] username]];
        [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
            if (!error)
              NSLog (@"You have %d Memories Saved", count);
            return cell;
    }
         
    #pragma mark - IB Actions
    
    - (IBAction)sendMemories:(UIButton *)sender {
        
        PFObject *memories = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Memories"];
        memories[@"Memories"] = self.memoriesField.text;
        [memories setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
        [memories saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded){
                NSLog(@"succeeded");
                self.memoriesField.text = nil;
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"problem");
                UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Our Apologies" message:@"Your Memory was not Recieved" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                
                UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
                
                [alert addAction: defaultAction];
    
                
            }
        NSString *memories = [self.memoriesField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            [self.view endEditing:YES];
        
        if ([memories length] == 0)
        {
            UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Memory Recieved!" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            
            UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
            
            [alert addAction: defaultAction];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                }
            }];
        }
    
    - (IBAction)logOut:(id)sender {
        [PFUser logOut];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
    
    }
    
    #pragma mark - UITextField Delegate Methods
    
    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
        
        if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }
        
        return YES;
    
    }
    @end
```

Comment: Error --  No visible @interface for 'UITableViewCell' declares the selector 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:'

Comment: I have a feeling that I have things in the wrong place. I am not sure that ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear are ordered correctly or that they have the right segments of code inside them.

Comment: Why are you using a table view to display a single value? Why not UILabel, e.g.? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/

Comment: wait, you can use UILabel for data being pulled from Parse.com?  I want the finale product to read "You have 15 Memories Saved".  Where 15 is the count of their userName in that string on Parse.com.  If that makes sense.  I am a total noob.

Comment: Where you have the `NSLog("You have... saved")` do `label.text = @"You have... saved";` instead.

Comment: Ok, sorry for being such a novice, but should replace Label or Text with something from my code?  Are either of those a generic variable that I need to replace with cellCount or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't know about Parse.com, but it seems that you can use a `UILabel` instead of the `UITableView` that you are using, storing it in a property `label`. Then run the code that you have to set the label text:

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Memories"];
    [query whereKey:@"senderName" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] username]];
    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
          NSLog (@"You have %d Memories Saved", count);
          self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have %d Memories Saved", count];
        }
```